# voice recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, voice

during Zimmerman trial, each camp claimed the yell for help recorded belonged to their side.  given that Zimmerman is still aside and the recording still exist, could there be some scientific way to tell which way?

Answer (score 2):

There exist DSP techniques to estimate anatomical differences in head resonance (vowel formant centers, etc.) and glottal fold characteristics (e.g. Tenor vs Bass, etc.) used in music, speech and audiology research.  However there may or may not be sufficient statistical difference is these areas between the two possible vocalization sources, or the mic response may not been sufficient to pick up and record the frequency bands and transients of interest with sufficient detail (too low S/N, etc.)

If sufficient recordings of one of the voice sources do not exist, the vocal production might have to be estimated from MRI data reconstruction of the vocal tract, which introduces its own set of estimation errors.